# Maria Db making function using if statement

Tags: sql, function, mariadb

I'm working on EnitityFrameWork and trying to use Database Function. I am not familiar with making function with Database . This is What I made. The error says syntax error " for line 16 which is "RETURN x"

```
delimiter //
CREATE FUNCTION CREATE_TIME4(hour1 int, minute1 INT, second1 INT) 
RETURNS VARCHAR(50)
BEGIN
    DECLARE x VARCHAR(50);
    DECLARE H VARCHAR(10);
    DECLARE M VARCHAR(10);
    DECLARE S VARCHAR(10);
    IF LENGTH(YEA) < 2 THEN 
        SET H = '0' + CONCAT(hour1);
    IF LENGTH(MON) < 2 THEN 
        SET M = '0' + CONCAT(minute1);
    IF LENGTH(SEC) < 2 THEN 
        SET S = '0' + CONCAT(second1); 
    SET x = CONCAT(H,':', M,':', S);
    RETURN x;
END//
```

Comment: Year, month, SECOND?  Not day?  See `DATE_FUNCTION()`.

Comment: the problem is I use this Function for Entity Framework that's why I can not use Date_Function

Answer (score 0):

You have lot of errors in the function which you have defined. I am only correcting the compilation mistakes.

```
CREATE FUNCTION CREATE_TIME4(@YEA int, @MON INT, @SEC INT) 
RETURNS VARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @x VARCHAR(50);
    DECLARE @H VARCHAR(10);
    DECLARE @M VARCHAR(10);
    DECLARE @S VARCHAR(10);
    IF LEN(@YEA) < 2 
        SET @H = CONCAT('0', @YEA);
    IF LEN(@MON) < 2 
        SET @M = CONCAT('0', @MON);
    IF LEN(@SEC) < 2 
        SET @S = CONCAT('0', @SEC); 
    SET @x = CONCAT(@H,':', @M,':', @S);
    RETURN @x;
END
```

Comment: @variables are not used that way in MariaDB.